# How to send values to a controller?

Tags: php, model-view-controller, zend-framework

How can I pass a result to a particular controller's action in zend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use POST and GET as any standard HTML Forms.

Just don't forget to build correctly your URL :

Using GET : (baseUrl)/(Controller)/(Action)/Param1/Value1/Param2/Value2

Using POST : (baseUrl)/(Controller)/(Action)